# WPF image moving and rotating

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation, storyboard

First of all I place here my situation sreenshot:

[image]

So I need to move these cars(cars are `Image`s) where the arrow goes. 
For driving straight I use this function:

```
    private static void Eiti(Image target, double naujasX, double naujasY, double greitis, char kelias)
    {
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(target);
        var left = Canvas.GetLeft(target);
        top = Double.IsNaN(top) ? 0 : top;
        left = Double.IsNaN(left) ? 0 : left;
        naujasY = Paveikslas.canvasY(naujasY, kelias);

        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        greitis = 100 / greitis;                // apverciamas greitis, kad butu logiska
        storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;

        if (naujasY != -1)                         // isejimo simbolis (escape)
        {
            DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(top, naujasY, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(greitis));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(anim1, target);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));
            storyboard.Children.Add(anim1);

            DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(left, naujasX, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(greitis));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(anim2, target);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim2, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
            storyboard.Children.Add(anim2);
        }

        storyboard.Begin();

    }
```

> and it's working good for me!

But now I have problem with rotating and driving car at the same time (for example like in my `screenshot` driving through green square).

> Is there any function or other ways to solve this ?

Comment: Take a look at [MatrixAnimationUsingPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.matrixanimationusingpath(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @armandasalmd use can use 3 [`DoubleAnimationUsingPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath(v=vs.100).aspx) for 3 sources `X`, `Y`, and `Angle` (for some `RotateTransform`)